# Projections satisfying $\| Px-Qx \| <\|x \|$ for nonzero $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a f.d inner product space with subspace $M,N$ and corresponding orthogonal projections $Q,P$. I need to prove that if $\| Px-Qx \| <\|x \|$ for all nonzero $x$, then $\dim M=\dim N$. As a hint, I was told to prove $P|_M$ and $Q|_N$ are injective.

I am totally lost. First of all, I don't have geometric intuition for this. Second, I don't see how the hint would help, and finally, I don't see how to prove it...

Help!

Comment: What is f.d? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat finite dimensional

Comment: For your second question, note that $P|_M$ injective implies $\dim M\leq\dim N$. For your third, what does your inequality reduce to if $x\in\ker P|_M$ is nonzero?

Comment: @stewbasic ah!! So elegant! Thanks! Could you also help me out with visualizing this?

Comment: In 2D you can imagine a circle $S$ whose diameter is the line segment $(0,x)$. Then $Px$ and $Qx$ lie on $S$ since $Px\perp(x-Px)$. Thus $\|Px-Qx\|\leq\|x\|$ with equality iff $(Px,Qx)$ is also a diameter for $S$. This requires that $Px\perp Qx$, which implies $Px\in\ker Q|_N$, $Qx\in\ker P|_M$.

Comment: @stewbasic perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For geometric intuition, let $S$ be the sphere whose diameter is the segment $(0,x)$. Since the segments $(0,Px)$ and $(Px,x)$ are orthogonal, $Px$ lies on $S$, and similarly for $Qx$. Thus $\|Px-Qx\|\leq\|x\|$, with equality iff the segment $(Px,Qx)$ is also a diameter of $S$. This happens iff the four points are coplanar and form a rectangle, which implies $x=Px+Qx$, so $Px\in\ker Q|_N$ and $Qx\in\ker P|_M$.

Algebraically, if $x\in\ker P|_M$ is nonzero, then $x\in M$, so $Qx=x$ and your given inequality becomes
$$
  \|x\|>\|Px-Qx\|=\|x\|,
$$
a contradiction. Thus $\ker P|_M=0$. That is, $P|_M$ is an injection from $M$ to $N$, so $\dim M\leq\dim N$. The reverse inequality follows similarly.

[image: x and its projections]

Comment: If we take $M=0$ and $0\neq N\subsetneq V$, then $ \|Px-Qx\| = \|Px\| <\| x\|$ which seems to contradict the contrapositive. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Arrow Note that the condition must hold for all nonzero $x$. In particular if $M=0$ and $N\neq0$, we can pick any nonzero $x\in N$ and we have $\|Px-Qx\|=\|Px\|=\|x\|$, so the condition fails.

Comment: @stewbasic it's an old question, but... How can you even restrict $P$ to $M$, if $P$ is not $M$-invariant?

Comment: @stewbasic another thing: the proof works even if the projections are not orthogonal, even though the geometric intuition doesn't hold any more... am I right?

Comment: @paul Restriction only refers to reducing the domain, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics). If you prefer, replace $\ker P|_M$ by $\ker P\cap M$.

Comment: @Paul you are right, for non orthogonal projections the proof still works, but the converse statement no longer holds.

Comment: @stewbasic thanks! For restrictions, I'm familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace#Formal_description). The syntax looks the same. How can I know understand which one is meant?

Comment: @Paul unfortunately only from context (eg if a proof shows $W$ is $T$-invariant before mentioning $T|_W$, it probably means the second sense). Note that the only difference is that in the second sense the codomain also shrinks; if $f:A\to B$ and $\mathrm{im}\,f\subseteq B'\subseteq B$, it is common (but not strictly correct) to treat $f$ as if it were a function $A\to B'$.